# How to set Xlib window background transparent?

Tags: background, transparent, xlib

I want to create a window that has transparent background. How to do it?

I use `XSetBackground(display, gc, 0)`, the background is *black*. I change the depth of the screen to `32`. The result is still black. Here is my code:

```
    display = XOpenDisplay(getenv("DISPALY"));
    screen = DefaultScreen(display);
    depth = DefaultDepth(display,screen);
    printf("depth: %d\n", depth);
    rootwindow = RootWindow(display,screen);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.background_pixel = 0; 

    window = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, 1440, 900, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput,
                    vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);

    gc = XCreateGC (display, window, 0, NULL);
   XSetBackground(display, gc, 0L);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- make sure window depth is 32
- set value of alpha bits for transparent areas
- make sure you are running composite manager that can handle transparency correctly

See my question ["How to upload 32bit pixmap to server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492275/how-to-upload-32-bit-image-to-server-side-pixmap) as an example of how to set alpha channel value

**upd:** also make sure your window is created with associated colormap (I don't know the reason behind this, but I was not able to get 32 bit window displayed correctly without colormap)

Comment: I saw your page before.XMatchVisualInfo func make the depth 32.The next two steps I don't know how to do.can you give me a simple example that create a window with transparent background.I use XClearArea to make an area show the background of the window.I want to set the background of the window transparent.So, I can get a subregion that is transparent.

Comment: I got a page,the example is below:  [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395179/empty-or-transparent-window-with-xlib-showing-border-lines-only/23053020#23053020)
 But the background is black still.Anyone has a good solution?

Comment: Just transfer transparent pixels (not black). Pre-fill RGBA32 pixmap on the client, set A to some value and then do XPutImage

Comment: exemple using node-x11: https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11/blob/master/examples/smoketest/transpwindow.js

Comment: I'm so sorry that I can't understand your .js code example clearly.Can you give me a simple example that just create a window with transparent background using C or C++.With the best thanks!!!For I am a newbie.I use [create 32 depth window example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395179/empty-or-transparent-window-with-xlib-showing-border-lines-only/23053020#23053020)for example

Comment: Whether should it done by compositing clients like many WMs,like Metacity, Compiz etc. or standalone compositors like compton or xcompmgr? Can I use pure xlib and it's extention--xrender,to do this work?It looks difficult ,even no effect.

Comment: not quite sure - do you want to write your own composite manager? In that case you need Composite & Damage extension to get up to date set of pixmaps representing window surfaces and Render or GLX to efficiently composite it into single image

Comment: I use xcompmgr as  compositor.When I run it, the 32 bit window is abnormal.It hides and apears sometime.the root window becomes gray.

Comment: My system supports transparent windows (using `transset` from a terminal applies transparency to any window), yet the root depth on my system appears to be only 24. Is setting a depth of 32 really required?