# Why I set xlib window background transparent failed？

Tags: c, linux, window, transparent, xlib

I use the following code to get a transparent window, but it returns black.What's wrong with me? And, can anybody give me a simple example to create a window with transparent background?THANKS!

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.background_pixel = 0;

    Window win = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, 300, 200, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
    XSelectInput(display, win, StructureNotifyMask);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, win, 0, 0);

    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, win, &wm_delete_window, 1);

    XMapWindow(display, win);

    int keep_running = 1;
    XEvent event;

    while (keep_running) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        switch(event.type) {
            case ClientMessage:
                if (event.xclient.message_type == XInternAtom(display, "WM_PROTOCOLS", 1) && (Atom)event.xclient.data.l[0] == XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 1))
                    keep_running = 0;

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(display, win);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me:

kde:

[image]

openbox + xcompmgr:

[image]

Most likely you are not running composite manager. Try to start `xcompmgr` command

Also check `_NET_WM_CM_S0` selection owner - it should [point to a window created by composite manager](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.4/ar01s08.html).

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    Atom cmAtom = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_CM_S0", 0);
    Window cmOwner = XGetSelectionOwner(display, cmAtom);

    printf("Composite manager window: %i\n", cmOwner);

    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Update:

Try to set override-redirect to prevent WM decorations from obscuring your window.

```
attr.border_pixel = 0;
attr.background_pixel = 0;
attr.override_redirect = 1; /* this line added */

Window win = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, 300, 200, 0, 
vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual, 
CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel | CWOverrideRedirect /* and this one*/, &attr);
```

Comment: Thank you.You are so generous to anwser my questions.  I run the xcompmgr already. The code you given print "Composite manager window: 0".Is this correct?what should I do next?

Comment: "Composite manager window: 0" means that you are not running composite manager. Are you sure it is still running when you check selection owner?

Comment: this is what I have: `laplace@laplace-Mint ~ $ xcompmgr &
[1] 6656
laplace@laplace-Mint ~ $ ./cmowner 
Composite manager window: 29360129`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to run xcompmgr.Here is :# xcompmgr &
# ./test
Composite manager window: 16777217 ....But the window I create is still unsee .[Just as the comment I given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051594/how-to-set-xlib-window-background-transpatrent/23052541?noredirect=1#comment35279989_23052541)

Comment: which wm are you using? I just tried icewm (black window, no transparency) and fwvm (transparent window). My screenshot is under kde / kwm. If your wm reparents window to add title / borders and new parent window is not transparent you'll not get transparent window as a result

Comment: The backgroud is black!

Comment: try to set override-redirect flag (see update in answer)

Comment: According to your  
suggest：# ./test
Composite manager window: 25165825
vinfo.depth: 32      The background is black still!

Comment: Is there any software will interference the xcompmgr&openbox?Any extra settings for xserver or something?

Comment: I just used freshly installed openbox & xcompmgr for screenshot. No idea why it fails for you. What is result of `xdpyinfo | grep -i composite` on your box?

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `# xdpyinfo | grep -i composite
    Composite` yes, Composite extention is loaded.-_-"

Comment: Hey,[I find a page just now](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xcompmgr)**hsetroot**,I set it.My window is steady.But it shows like a 24 bit window.No special phenomenon happend when I run xcompmgr.I want to say, there should be some extra settings affect my system.According to my thought, do you have any suggestions?Thank you in advance.I think you are an  expert for xwindow somehow.

Comment: I create a new thread for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130581/how-to-use-openboxxcompmgr-correctly

Comment: what does this mean:'"urxvt allows for true transparent background if you are using a compositing manager that supports that. I use xcompmgr with Openbox (no LXDE) which does true transparency. True, xterm will not do transparent backgrounds."'

Comment: no idea. Likely means it tries to create 32-bit window and allows you to set background with alpha cjannel