# How to use Openbox+xcompmgr correctly?

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, xlib

I use xcompmgr to make the 32 bit window to has a transparent background.The WM is Openbox.But When I run my 32 bit window example,the window is black not transparent.The result I want is set something make xcompmgr work fine.I saw a page "[Background turns light gray briefly after logging in (e.g. in Openbox)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xcompmgr)",**hsetroot**.I run hsetroot,my window become steady,but like a 24 bit window with a black background.Is there any ideas to meet my demand?

Comment: Can anybody give me some advice?I really need your help.

Comment: Please don't just ask the same question again if you don't get answers. The reason you don't have any answers is that there's absolutely no info here... Maybe try adding the code you have that does not work, an example of something slightly different that works if you have it, info on why openbox is relevant -- does your code work in other WMs? Explanation on what a "steady but 24bit-like" window is...

Answer (score 0):

Even if this message is quite old, maybe I can help someone else :
xcompmgr don't work very well with openbox. You can use compton instead.
Compton is a fork of xcompmgr.