# How to have a transparent window background using FLTK

Tags: window, x11, fltk

I am working on a project and would like to create a window with a transparent background, but can't seem to find out how to do this.  The call I am making is:

```
XWindow win = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, fl_xid(Root), winWidth, winHeight, 5, 5, 0, 0, NULL);
```

The 'NULL' value is not valid as it is looking for an unsigned int.  Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the first post in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fltkgeneral/Ga_FEutXUKk/f5y668eWu6IJ

Comment: Note that Lubuntu does not use a compositor by default.  Even if the X window opacity is changed, it is necessary to have a compositor, such as xcompmgr or compton, etc., running in order to achieve transparency.  You typically install these to launch at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by 'transparent background'.  If you want complete transparency, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395179/empty-or-transparent-window-with-xlib-showing-border-lines-only/13397150#13397150).

If you want opacity and are using a compositor you should be able to do something like this:

```
Atom atom = XInternAtom(fl_display, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY", False); 
uint opacity = 0x80000000; /* 0x0 .. 0xffffffff */
XChangeProperty(fl_display, fl_xid(win), atom, XA_CARDINAL, 32,
                PropModeReplace, (unsigned char*)&opacity, 1L);
```